PostgreSQL pg_hint_plan index hint is ignored for some executions of the same query
I'm trying to use pg_hint_plan to force the query planner to use a specific index for one of my queries. Looking at the server logs, it appears to work most of the time, but for some executions of the same query the index is still not used.
I have enabled extended logging to debug, and the logs usually look like this:
2024-07-15 14:35:29 UTC:192.168.42.237(53348):userapi_segmentation@userapi_segmentation:[7114]:LOG: available indexes for IndexOnlyScan(segmentation_game): game_all_flat_fields
2024-07-15 14:35:29 UTC:192.168.42.237(53348):userapi_segmentation@userapi_segmentation:[7114]:STATEMENT: /*+ IndexOnlyScan(segmentation_game game_all_flat_fields) */
SELECT count(*) FROM public.segmentation_game
WHERE ($1 OR (id BETWEEN $2 AND $3))
AND (("numericSegmentGroupIds" @> $4))
AND ($5 = false OR "hasAtLeastOnePushDeviceEnabled" = true)
AND ($6 IS NULL OR "utcOffset" >= $7)
AND ($8 IS NULL OR "utcOffset" < $9)
AND ($10::TIME IS NULL OR "usualSessionStartTime" >= $11)
AND ($12::TIME IS NULL OR "usualSessionStartTime" < $13)
2024-07-15 14:35:29 UTC:192.168.42.237(53348):userapi_segmentation@userapi_segmentation:[7114]:LOG: pg_hint_plan:
used hint:
IndexOnlyScan(segmentation_game game_all_flat_fields)
not used hint:
duplication hint:
error hint:

But for some queries, it looks like this (auto_explain is enabled):
2024-07-15 13:00:12 UTC:192.168.184.85(34822):userapi_segmentation@userapi_segmentation:[2323]:LOG:  duration: 10031.586 ms  execute S_1: /*+ IndexScan(segmentation_game game_all_flat_fields) */
    SELECT count(*) FROM public.segmentation_game
    WHERE ($1 OR (id BETWEEN $2 AND $3))
        AND (("numericSegmentGroupIds" @> $4))
        AND ($5 = false OR "hasAtLeastOnePushDeviceEnabled" = true)
        AND ($6 IS NULL OR "utcOffset" >= $7)
        AND ($8 IS NULL OR "utcOffset" < $9)
        AND ($10::TIME IS NULL OR "usualSessionStartTime" >= $11)
        AND ($12::TIME IS NULL OR "usualSessionStartTime" < $13)
2024-07-15 13:00:12 UTC:192.168.184.85(34822):userapi_segmentation@userapi_segmentation:[2323]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 't', $2 = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', $3 = 'ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff', $4 = '{2513,379}', $5 = 't', $6 = '-540', $7 = '-540', $8 = '-525', $9 = '-525', $10 = NULL, $11 = NULL, $12 = NULL, $13 = NULL
2024-07-15 13:00:12 UTC:192.168.184.85(34822):userapi_segmentation@userapi_segmentation:[2323]:LOG:  duration: 10031.576 ms  plan:
    Query Text: /*+ IndexScan(segmentation_game game_all_flat_fields) */
    SELECT count(*) FROM public.segmentation_game
    WHERE ($1 OR (id BETWEEN $2 AND $3))
        AND (("numericSegmentGroupIds" @> $4))
        AND ($5 = false OR "hasAtLeastOnePushDeviceEnabled" = true)
        AND ($6 IS NULL OR "utcOffset" >= $7)
        AND ($8 IS NULL OR "utcOffset" < $9)
        AND ($10::TIME IS NULL OR "usualSessionStartTime" >= $11)
        AND ($12::TIME IS NULL OR "usualSessionStartTime" < $13)
    Aggregate  (cost=128283.52..128283.53 rows=1 width=8)
      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on segmentation_game  (cost=20022.53..128283.51 rows=1 width=0)
            Recheck Cond: ("numericSegmentGroupIds" @> '{2513,379}'::integer[])
            Filter: ("hasAtLeastOnePushDeviceEnabled" AND ("utcOffset" >= '-540'::integer) AND ("utcOffset" < '-525'::integer))
            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "game_numericSegmentGroupIds_gin"  (cost=0.00..20022.53 rows=29137 width=0)
                  Index Cond: ("numericSegmentGroupIds" @> '{2513,379}'::integer[])

I understand that for the second query, the planner might think that the heap scan is actually better (because there's the condition on id with a large range 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 to ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff), but I thought the IndexOnlyScan would force it to use the index provided anyway. When I execute this exact query (including hint) using a 3rd party client, it uses the index correctly and the query is 10 times faster.
The queries are executed on a Postgres 13.13 server on AWS RDS, using a Java application.
Is there any way to actually force the planner to use the index, no matter what the query condition looks like? Any help is greatly appreciated!
Edit:
Adding db params exported from RDS (accessing the conf file is unfortunately not possible afaik, so I exported the parameter group containing all settings):
https://gist.github.com/shinlang/ff06b0b40c4232eb2b00e9096c2710d6

Could you please share your postgresql.conf configuration? That is closely related to the execution plans.

I've added an export of the RDS parameter group, which is the closest to a postgresql.conf I can get from RDS I think :/ I hope it's readable enough.

Looks like most of the configuration is default: "value":null. That doesn't help when you're looking for performance. I would start with a proper configuration for high performance, then check for index usage and afterwards maybe spend some time on hints. You might have to improve the statistics as well, create your own custom stats.

The 2nd excerpt of log file doesn't look like it is the correct part of the log. The statement should be logged twice, once before execution (when  pg_hint_plan.debug_print kicks in) and once after execution (if auto_explain.log_min_duration kicks in)  It looks like you quoted the wrong one.

@jjanes You're right, I've edited the second example. This seems to be the complete log for this query, there's no debug log from pg_hint_plan at all. I would have expected it to at least log that it didn't take the hint, but here just seems to be nothing. It's also ONLY happening for those queries with the 000... to fff... conditions, all other variations of this query do work with the hint.

Yeah, that is weird.  Can you reproduce this when running those queries using psql?  I wonder if your java code is doing something strange which disables the hints.
